# DefaultListModel confusion

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I am trying a different approach just for practicing purpose. I know it seems seems ridiculous. My goal is to retrieve numbers array when constructor initialize. But I couldn't do it. How can I do this?

```
public class Myclass  extends JPanel{
 String[]num={"1","2","3"};

public Myclass() {
    JList list=new JList(new mymodel(num));
    JScrollPane pane=new JScrollPane(list);
      add(pane);

}
class mymodel extends DefaultListModel{

    public mymodel(String[] numbers) {
        super();
    }


}
public static void  main(String...args){
JFrame  frame=new JFrame();
frame.setContentPane(new d());
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setSize(300,300);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 2) Don't set the size of top level containers.  Instead layout the content & call `pack()`. 3) Don't extend `JPanel`.  Instead create & use an instance of one. 4) A single blank line of white space in source code is *always* enough.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: Also note that `super()` is invoked implicitly; there's no need to invoke it explicitly; step into it in the debugger to see the call stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to iterate through the array, adding each element to the `ListModel`. Also, consider replacing `MyPanel extends JPanel` with a method that returns a `JPanel`.

```
private static class MyModel extends DefaultListModel {

    public MyModel(String[] numbers) {
        for (String string : numbers) {
            this.addElement(string);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/):

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

/**
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17904479/230513
 */
public class Test {

    private static class MyPanel extends JPanel {

        String[] num = {"1 One", "2 Two", "3 Three"};

        public MyPanel() {
            this.setLayout(new GridLayout());
            JList list = new JList(new MyModel(num));
            list.setVisibleRowCount(3);
            JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(list);
            this.add(pane);
        }
    }

    private static class MyModel extends DefaultListModel {

        public MyModel(String[] numbers) {
            for (String string : numbers) {
                this.addElement(string);
            }
        }
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new MyPanel());
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```